# Android : start screen capture without creating new activity

Tags: android, screen-capture, android-mediaprojection

I am trying to record screen video using MediaProjection. I want to capture video in the same activity and not start another activity.
 I have gone through a few tutorials. In these tutorials, a call is made to startActivityForResult with `createScreenCaptureIntent()` as the first argument, which basically asks for permissions and starts the screen capture. And the `resultCode` is passed to `getMediaProjection()`

```
startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
```

It is necessary that the main activity is captured, so just frame replacement instead of a new activity. I have a floating button in the main activity, listening to stop recording.

So, I wanted to know if it is possible? Or if we can create a similar scenario leading to same events, wihtout creating a new activity of course? Or If this is not possible, how can we stop recording given that we are now in a new activity.

Thank you for your time.